# Cannot understand the following code?

Tags: c#

Can somebody explain this code in detail.basically how it works?

`Int32[] numbers = a.Split(',').Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray();`

Comment: It splits string `a` on comma, parses each result as `int` and casts the final result to an array of `int`s. What have you tried?

Comment: This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question)

Comment: Read about `Split`, `Select`, `Parse` and `ToArray` methods before asking questions what they do

Comment: @Soner nowadays that's called ["off-topic"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/).

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not clear how this is off-topic. What do I miss?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, I still can't get used to new closing system..

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don't know whether you're serious or whether you did or didn't read the blog, but not any question containing any code is ontopic. See also the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) linked in the close message. Hypothetical questions like this are off-topic. SO is not a replacement for running the code and reading the manual for each function used.

Comment: @CodeCaster I was serious. And the last sentence of your comment answered by surprise. That's what I missed. Thanks. Perhaps that's the exact wording of the comment that should be used when bashing a question. "Off-topic" is a bit cryptic, especially to a newcommers and lazy donkeys not reading all the info around.   :)

Comment: You should surely read up on methods you don't understand. But it seems like everything is pretty self descriptive. `Split` splits, `Select` selects, `Parse` parses and `ToArray` turns various things into arrays. What may help is to cut a complex statement up and see its intermediate results on their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's pretend

```
string a = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
```

Then

```
Int32[] numbers = a.Split(',').Select(s => Int32.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Will create an array named `numbers` that will contain the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

Answer (score 2):

Its converting a comma separated list of integers encoded as a string into an array of integers.

Answer (score 2):

It takes a string consisting of comma separated integers and converts this string to an array of integers:

```
"1,2,3,4,5" -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it fills an array of 32 bits numbers with the results of the conversion of the elements contained in "a" to integers on 32 bits.

as an example : "1,2,3" would become an array like this : [1,2,3]